# Viewing\Editing SQL CE 4 Database

Tags: sql-server, webmatrix, sql-server-ce

Does anyone know a way of viewing and editing an existing SQL CE 4.0 databse?  I've tried using SQL Server 2008 but it looks as if it only supports version 3.5.

I read on Scott Guthrie's blog that you can use WebMatrix but I can't figure out how.

The blog article is located here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

and WebMatrix is located here:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/06/introducing-webmatrix.aspx

Thanks

Davy

Comment: I have a list of some other tools that work with SQL Compact 4.0: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open/create an app (could just be some blank folder on your desktop) then click the database tab on the bottom left.  All the basics for messing with a SQL Compact 4 DB is in there.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I can create a folder on my desktop called tempSite.  When I open this in webmatrix I can create a DB but it defaults it to tempSite.sdf.  How do I open an existing sdf?  I tried new connection but I'm not sure what settings to enter for this.

Comment: OK, I was being dumb.  I've copied the sdf into my tempSite.dbf, refreshed the tab in WebMatrix and it all works.  Thanks Erik.